# Proving $3\;|a_1-a_3|+|b_1-b_3|\leq 3\;|a_1-a_2|+|b_1-b_2|+3\;|a_2-a_3|+|b_2 - b_3| $

Tags: inequality

I'd like to prove that
$$
3\;|a_1-a_3|+|b_1-b_3|\leq 3\;|a_1-a_2|+|b_1-b_2|+3\;|a_2-a_3|+|b_2 - b_3|
$$

Obs.: I don't know if this is possible.

#### My tentative (edited)

For the left side,

\begin{equation}
3\mid (a_1 - a_2) + (a_2 - a_3) \mid + \mid(r_1 - r_2) + (r_2 - r_3) \mid,
\end{equation}

however, I don't know how to continue...

Comment: I think you are almost there. Just check your sign mistake.

Comment: Thanks! I corrected the signals. But, I can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the triangular inequality twice $|a_2-a_3|+|a_1-a_2|\ge |a_1-a_3|$ and a similar one for $b$'s.